# Which condition i need for laravel validation if i need to check max strlen just for numbers from a string which contains comma and dot

Tags: php, laravel

I have this situation:

An input which can contain max chars 11 ( e.g. 12345678.00 ) 10 numbers and 1 comma or dot.
I need to check only if max strlen of numbers is grater than 10, for example user cannot insert this number 12345678901. This input is for price.

So, i use laravel framework and in my function at the beggining i already extracted the max strlen value of numbers of that input but i don't know how to put in laravel condition.

My function:

```
$price = (int) filter_var($request->price, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$max = strlen($price);
$this->validate($request, 
//rules for input validation
[
  'price' => ??
],

//message for input validation
[
  'price.??'  => 'Some text error'
]);
```

If exist another way to verify the condition in php and send the message please tell me. For clarifying i cannot use numeric number, or max|min condition..

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a custom validator. For that you can follow this blog. https://laraveldaily.com/how-to-create-custom-validation-rules-laravel

Or Create a validator class by running

```
php artisan make:rule StrDigitCalculator
```

This will create a class in App\Rules folder. Open `App\Rules\StrDigitCalculator.php` and paste code below so your custom validator will look like this

```
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
    
class StrDigitCalculator implements Rule
{
    
    /**
    * Determine if the validation rule passes.
    *
    * @param  string  $attribute
    * @param  mixed  $value
    * @return bool
    */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $int = (int) filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        return strlen($int) == 10 : true : false;    
    }
    
    /**
    * Get the validation error message.
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function message()
    {
        // Your custom message for this validation
        return 'Validation Fails';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! After this for calling i use this: $this->validate($request, ['price' => new StrDigitCalculator]);

Comment: Yes @AlexandruValentin, You are absolutely going right